# Weird response received using Promise

Tags: javascript

```
    vm.imageR = $resource("", {}, {
        getFile: {
            url: '/api/imager/:fileId',
            method: 'GET',
            transformResponse: function(data, headersGetter) { return { data : data }},
            isArray: false,
            params: {
                fileId: '@fileId'
            }
        },
    ...
```

This is what I receive:

`"�PNG
IHDRX�7�"�PLTE���V�3R�-���O�(��������������S�/���P�*��h�H��������θ������׫����奥���ᴴ�����ށ�����O�E������...`

How to correctly parse the image to display as image in HTML (set as `src` in image)?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: set the correct content type header. `Content-Type: image/png`

Comment: Where do I set it? @Ibu

Comment: It depends on what framework (javascript or server side) you are using. You will have to provide more details

Comment: Angular $resource @Ibu

Answer (score 0):

If you really have to load the image this way, you will have to base64 the image data being returned on the server side and append that string on your img src.

```
// in this format
var imgData = "data:image/png;base64,"+theBase64Data;
```

Otherwise you will have to use an image tag to perform the request.

```
var img = document.createElement("img"); 
img.src = '/api/imager/'+fieldId; // whatever the fieldId is
// append it to the dom.
```

The second option make more sense since you are getting the image from the server anyway, why base64 it?

Comment: I am getting the image, but the correct text that starts with "iVBOR" is only at Preview tab of Developer Tools. I want to get that text, but can't.

Comment: `<img id="newImage" src="data:image/png;base64,�PNG&#13;&#10;&#10;&#13;IHDRX�7�&quot;�PLTE���V�3R�-�...` is what I get.

Comment: The preview tab is Chrome converting binary data into a base64. Only for display purpose.

Comment: @guautemoczihuataneho `theBase64Data=btoa(yourResponseData)` then use Ibu's answer

Comment: `btoa(myResponseData)` gives me only short `W29iamVjdCBPYmplY3Rd`

Comment: Then use my second option

Comment: @guautemoczihuataneho i think that's the oiutput you get if you btoa the entire response object... but your png string is in the data property of the response, so it would be something like `btoa(response.data)`

Answer (score 0):

It's weird, but this was the only change that worked:

Before:

```
vm.getFile = function (fileId) {
    return vm.imageR.getFile({ fileId: fileId });
};
```

Now:

```
vm.getFile = function (fileId) {
    var retVal = vm.imageR.getFile({ fileId: fileId });
    return retVal;
};
```

Really weird. :)